# Can I treat an instance of one class as an attribute of another

Tags: python, subclass, delegation

Ideally I would like to extend an instance of PIL's image class to include some custom methods; Image doesn't support this however, so I need to change tack. Delegation seems to be the most conventional alternative, but before I stumbled upon this aspect of python I had toyed with the idea of creating my custom class with an attribute that functioned as an instance of the PIL Image class. I've not seen this done anywhere else, but is this essentially the same thing as delegation?

```
import Image

MyImageClass():
    def __init__(self, filepath):
        self.attrA = ...
        self.attrB = ...
        self.attrc = ...

        self.img = Image.open(filepath)

    def method_A(self):
        ...
    def method_B(self):

im = MyImageClass('/path/to/png')
im.self.img.thumbnail((100,100))
```

Comment: This is pretty much basic OO programming - look up the "has-a" relationship for an example of objects stored in attributes.  (Also, I'm pretty sure `im.self.img` should be `im.img` - I get an AttributeError with the first version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. This is no different than:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'test'

im = Foo()
print im.bar.upper()
```

Notice that it is `im.bar`, not `im.self.bar`.

`self` in `__init__` is the same as `im` so `self.bar` in `__init__` is the same as `im.bar` outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. `im.bar.upper()` - I hadn't thought of it like that!

Answer (score 1):

Of course instances can be attributes of classes. But you say that you want an enhanced Image class - so extend Image:

```
#take this with a grain of salt - I didn't test the code
from PIL.Image import Image

MyImageClass(Image):
    def __init__(self): 
        super(MyImageClass, self).__init__()

        self.init_some = 'custom_stuff'            

    def method_A(self):
        ...
    def method_B(self):

im = MyImageClass.open('/path/to/png')
im.thumbnail((100,100))
```

**Update**

As OP pointed out [Image isn't designed to be subclassed by application code](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2006-March/003832.html). Hence my example is just a general example for inheritance.

Comment: I'd like to do this, but a post elsewhere on SO quotes the author of PIL as having said the following 'The Image class isn't designed to be subclassed by application code. if you want custom behaviour, use a delegating wrapper', hence my search for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the boundaries beween delegation, [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), aggregation, and other **has a** repationships are pretty blurry, as they all tend to share the same syntax, and with garbage collection there are no worries about ownership. What you call it will mainly depend on what you do with the objects, i.e. if  MyImageClass.method_A just calls self.img.method_A(), etc., it would be delegation.

I'm pretty sure you have seen this before, as every value in Python – including values of all attributes – is an instance of some type.

If your class **is an** Image, you're looking for inheritance. Your class should be a subclass of `Image`.